# Dynamic import component Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm trying to do this:

```
import Mainlogo from '@/logos/' +process.env.MAIN_SITE+ '.vue'
```

so i can get an environment based logo in my app but this doesn't work.

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ; (96:38)

Any ideas?

Comment: What's on line 96?

Comment: so are you importing an image (logo?)  or a vue file

Comment: Im importing a component that contains a SVG logo.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Vue environment variable docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables):

> Note that only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle

This means that all custom vars you want to use in your `.env` files must be prefixed with `VUE_APP_` if you want to pull them into the Vue app.  For example:

```
VUE_APP_SECRET=secret
VUE_APP_TITLE=myapp
```

You then access them in your code like:

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)
```

Comment: Well end goal is to set the process.env.MAIN_SITE trough my npm run build command. So the .env file wont be used.

Answer (score 1):

Ive managed to fix the issue doing the following:

```
<component :is="mainLogoLoader" class="logo"></component>

computed: {
  mainLogoLoader () {
    return () => import('@/logos/' +process.env.MAIN_SITE+ '.vue')
  }
},
```

and in module.exports:

```
MAIN_SITE: '"'+process.env.site+'"'
```

and my build command:

```
#site=mysite npm run build
```

Comment: I'd advise you to read this in case your bundling is not working as expected. In my case Webpack was creating a huge bundle with every file that could be imported into what in your case would be `process.env.MAIN_SITE`. Just in case, check with `webpack-bundle-analyzer` too. Webpack docs on dynamic imports: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import